# BigFloat not giving arbitrary precision

Tags: julia

I'm computing the digits of pi using the the Chudnovsky algorithm, and this is my code:

```
qMax = 1000000

L = Vector{BigFloat}(undef, qMax)
L[1] = 13591409
for q in 2:qMax
    L[q] = L[q-1] + 545140134
end

X = Vector{BigFloat}(undef, qMax)
X[1] = 1.0
for q in 2:qMax
    X[q] = X[q-1] * (-262537412640768000)
end

M = Vector{BigFloat}(undef, qMax)
M[1] = 1.0
for q in 2:qMax
    M[q] = M[q-1] * (((12*(q-2) + 2) * (12*(q-2)+6) * (12*(q-2) + 10))/(q-1)^3)
end

result = 0
for q in 1:qMax
    global result += (M[q] * L[q]) / X[q]
end
print(426880 * sqrt(10005) * 1/result)
```

But when I print the result, I get the same number of digits after the 3 for 1, 10, 1000 etc. values of qMax. How to get arbitrary many digits after the 3?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setprecision`:

```
julia> BigFloat(π)
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286198

julia> setprecision(BigFloat, 1024)
1024

julia> BigFloat(π)
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724586997

julia>
```

It's also possible to specify the precision in the constructor:

```
julia> BigFloat(π, precision=2048)
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726024914127372458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436789259036001133053054882046652138414695194151160943305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664308602139494639522473719070217986094370277053921717629317675238467481846766940513200056812714526357
```

However, operators don't seem to respect precision set in the constructor:

```
julia> setprecision(BigFloat, 10) # low precision
10

julia> BigFloat(1) / 3
0.3335 # OK, low precision, as expected

julia> BigFloat(1, precision=100) / 3
0.3335 # Low precision still!
```

I would expect higher precision to be propagated through the whole expression, but that doesn't seem to be the case...

EDIT: I opened [an issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/41171) about this behavior.

---

EDIT 2:

In the loop that updates `M`, all calculations are done on `q`, which is a regular integer, so when you divide by `(q-1)^3`, that will mean regular floating-point division, not involving `BigFloat`.

You can use `BigFloat` like this:

```
for q in 2:qMax
    # Use `BigFloat`!
    q_f = BigFloat(q)
    M[q] = M[q-1] * (
        (
            (12*(q_f-2) + 2) * (12*(q_f-2)+6) * (12*(q_f-2) + 10)
        ) / (q_f-1)^3
    )
end
```

Code:

```
setprecision(1024)

# your code...

println(426880 * sqrt(BigFloat(10005)) * 1/result)
println(BigFloat(π))
```

Output:

```
~/test $ julia so2.jl
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587042
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724586997
```

Comment: It looks like the division implicitly uses the default precision: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/0d94727a3855ddb0dd08648292f3394f662fefe8/base/mpfr.jl#L380

Comment: Any way to fix this? My pi values aren't correct after the first 15 digits for ever higher values of qMax

Comment: @lampbottle, calling `setprecision(BigFloat, 1024)` should make all `BigFloat` math use precision 1024

Comment: even after setting setprecision(BigFloat, 1000), only the first 15 digits of pi are correct.

Comment: @lampbottle, `sqrt(10005)` returns a regular `Float64`, not a `BigFloat`, which screws up the precision of `1 / result`

Comment: Wrapping it in Bigfloat(...,1000) still gives only the first 16 digits correct

Comment: @lampbottle, what exactly did you wrap in `BigFloat`? `sqrt(10005)` or `10005`?

Comment: BigFloat(sqrt(10005), 1000)

Comment: @lampbottle, `sqrt(10005)` is calculated (using `Float64`) _before_ the call to `BigFloat`, so the new `BigFloat` is basically a copy of that `Float64`. On the other hand, `sqrt(BigFloat(10005))` will compute the square root using `BigFloat` math. For example, `BigFloat(sqrt(2)) == 1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125`, but `sqrt(BigFloat(2)) == 1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462102`

Comment: Still only the first 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 digits are correct for qMax = 10^6

Comment: @lampbottle, turns out, there were still some `Float64` calculations. See edit

Comment: Where?————————-

Comment: @lampbottle, "EDIT 2" at the bottom of my answer

Comment: This is working but setting precision to 10,000 doesn’t produce 10,000 digits but approximately 1/3 of that

Comment: @lampbottle, `Float64` has precision of 64 (bits), which doesn't mean that a `Float64` is represented by 64 digits after the decimal point. This isn't surprising, is it? Same thing for `BigFloat`'s precision. See `?precision` in Julia REPL.