# Why is there a wrong last digit in the calculation of a BigFloat number?

Tags: floating-point, julia, precision

I write a simple code in Julia language:

```
a = BigFloat("10", precision=400)^(-10)
println(a)
```

The output is:

```
1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e-10
```

As you can see, there is a "3" after all zeros, and this is an error.
Is this a natural issue with BigFloat types, or is it one thing with the Julia way to do calculations?

I have been reading the documentation, but did not find anything there.

the test was made on site: [replit/julia](https://replit.com/languages/julia)

Comment: What happens if you increase `precision`?

Comment: Are you sure, that `BigFloat` is a `BigDecimal` and not using base 2 internally? The decimal number `1e-10` is periodic in base 2, i.e., you can't represent it exactly with finitely many digits.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I used this site: https://replit.com/languages/julia and set the precision to 40000 and the output is the same.

Comment: @chtz I'm no sure of the implementation of BigFloat. On my question i write "BigDecimal" by error, I want to say "BigFloat"

Comment: It seems to use base 2 internally, but still there is probably an issue how exponentiation is implemented. E.g., `a = BigFloat("1e-10", precision=4000)` is much more accurate than `a = BigFloat("10", precision=4000)^(-10)`.

Comment: @chtz you are right! where i can read the implementation of "^" operator in Julia?

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/17cfb8e65ead377bf1b4598d8a9869144142c84e/base/mpfr.jl#L598

Comment: Operations seems to use the default precision. You can use `setprecision(BigFloat, 4000)` to change that.

Comment: @chtz using setprecision(BigFloat, 4000) still drive me to a imprecision, but with setprecision(BigFloat, 16000) the value is exact! thankyou

Comment: As the power function is implemented as `x^y = exp(y*log(x))`, floating point errors are to be expected. For this reason usually a working precision is selected that is larger than the display precision, but if that is discarded between the two (or three) operations, non-trivial truncation errors will be the result. Can you explore how many of the 400 bits of the mantissa are actually dirty? What is the result from computing `1/10^10`?

Comment: @LutzLehmann when I calculate 1/10^(-10) the value is perfect: 10^10. But when I calculate 1/10^(10) the result is 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e-10 with the same error

Comment: Then the last decimal digit is just a result of converting the binary format of the BigFloat data into the decimal display string. From 400 bit one would expect about 120 valid decimal digits. So indeed a question is why only 78 digits are correct. See the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919412/bigfloat-not-giving-arbitrary-precision, which is the same as @chtz above, *"operators don't seem to respect precision set in the constructor"*. Or use the default precision in the conversion of the integers 1, 10.

Comment: @LutzLehmann perfect! This explains the all the thing. I will put this link on my answer bellow after read and make some tests. thankyou all guys!

Comment: To reformulate my last half-sentence, it is likely that in the automatic conversion of "naked" integer constants, like 1 and 10 here, the BigFloat constructor uses the global BigFloat precision as default, and not the individual precision of the other operands. And after that of course the precision of the result of an operation is the minimum of the precisions of the inputs.

Comment: @LutzLehmann According to the link which @mkrieger posted, it looks like for small enough integer exponents, Julia will call the function `mpfr_pow_si` -- but in any case the result `z` is constructed ignoring the precision of the input variables.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what precision you set, it's nothing wrong with BigFloat, nor with Julia. Binary floats cannot represent 0.1 (or  0.01, 0.001, etc.) exactly. If you try a regular Float64 value, you get

```
julia> BigFloat(0.1)
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

For a properly constructed BigFloat, it is better:

```
julia> BigFloat("0.1")
0.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

julia> BigFloat("0.1"; precision=1000)
0.100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
```

And this never ends, not even for precision=16000, or precision=16000000.

If you look at the bitstring of 0.1, you can see the pattern

```
julia> bitstring(0.1)
"0011111110111001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010"
```

Binary fractional values must always be a expressible as a sum

```
sum(b[n]/2^n)
```

where each `b[n]` is either zero or one. To get 0.1 exactly right, you need to repeat the pattern `1100110011001100...`, forever, so you need a vector `b` that is infinitely long.

Comment: While you are right that no negative power of 10 can be represented exactly as (finite) binary fraction, increasing the precision should increase the precision of the result -- but that requires setting the default precision due to the way it is implemented in Julia/MPFR.

Answer (score 1):

The operator "^", named "power" (or "exponential") uses the default `BigFloat` precision. So, to get more precision on all operations, you have to set this:

```
setprecision(BigFloat, 16000)
```

Then all the work will be done right.